# How can I allow multiple developers to push to my Git server set up in cPanel?

Tags: git, server, cpanel

I'm currently using cPanel which has git built in.

I can now execute the follow command on my local machine:
git clone username@domainname.com:/home/username/git/example

and it will successfully clone.
HOWEVER
Every time I clone it asks me for my SSH password.
I do not have a private/pub key system set up yet and I'd just like to know how to get it to work without disclosing my SSH password.

cPanel does not let me use sudo (just a heads up).

Answer (score 1):

Git simply uses SSH to authenticate users (most of the time). You have a few options. Either:

- Create user accounts on the server for all users who will need to push to the repository, and grant them all read/write access (at the OS level) to the git repository. They will be able to push with a password prompt (like you can now) or an SSH key pair.
- OR, Use SSH key pairs (not passwords) and add everyone's authorized key to the user account that owns the repository (currently your account), as described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server). (You may want to move the account to a `git` user, so you don't grant everyone access to all your files, unless you don't care about that.)

See the full Git Server Setup Docs [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

**Edit:** You seem to be following [this](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Host+Git+Repositories+on+a+cPanel+Account) guide. That guide seems horribly incomplete as it doesn't mention anything about adding additional users to the repository, and isn't setup in a way that seems to account for this. If you want a repository that more than one person can contribute to, perhaps you should **not** use cPanel to host it. (It is relatively simple to setup a repository for multi-user access following the steps in the official Git docs).

**Edit 2:** Git does support another type of authentication, *Smart HTTP*, in addition to SSH. It seems likely that this would work best if you want to continue using cPanel to host your Git repository, since this type of configuration essentially allows you to configure HTTP basic auth to allow users to push to the repository. Perhaps this use-case is intended by the guide you're following. This type of repository seems a little harder to set up than plain SSH, but perhaps it isn't too difficult if you can use cPanel to configure some things easily. Full details about how to set it up can be found on the [Git Smart HTTP](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) man page.